# Php mysql query loop if statement

Tags: php, mysql, loops, if-statement

I am trying to change the bgcolor of a tr of a php table, which gets its data from a loop, i think. I am a decent noob in all the php html stuff. Have been trying this whole day and cannot get it to change the bgcolor on finding the data.

the loop to get all data from mysql database works fine, now i don't know how to further the output to change bgcolor if older than 30 days and has status of OUT.

here is the code i currently have and trying. any help would be appreciated.

```
    $con=mysqli_connect($host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM data");

$sql77 = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE dt_in < date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND status != OUT";
$result77 = mysql_query($con,$sql77);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr bgcolor='lightgrey'>
<th>Signed in by</th>
<th>Reference Number</th>
<th>Asset Number</th>
<th>Make Model</th>
<th>Operating System</th>
<th>Office</th>
<th>Profile</th>
<th>Extra Apps</th>
<th>Time IN</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Time OUT</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
if (!$result77) {
echo "<tr>";
} else {
echo "<tr bgcolor='red'>";
}
  echo "<td>" . $row['who'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ref'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['asset'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['make_model'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['os'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['office'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['swp'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ea'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['dt_in'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['dt_out'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
echo $result77;
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is what finally solved my problem.

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
if(time() - strtotime($row['dt_in']) > 2592000 && $row['status'] != 'OUT') //2592000 sec == 30 days
{
echo "<tr class='MyOut'>";
} else {
echo "<tr>";
}
  echo "<td>" . $row['who'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ref'] . "</td>";
```

Comment: so... exactly where is `$result77` defined? It's not, anywhere in your code, so it will `if(!$result77)` will ALWAYS be true.

Comment: isn't $result77 defined here: $sql77 = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE dt_in < date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND status != OUT";
$result77 = mysql_query($con,$sql77);

Comment: The bgcolor attribute is not supported in html5 and is deprecated in html 4.01.  Use css instead.

Comment: My apologies. I missed the fetch call.

Comment: still have no idea what to do, busy trying to google it and make some sense of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there are some problems with this query `SELECT * FROM data WHERE dt_in < date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND status != OUT`

One problem is OUT needs single quotes around it (as I assume status is a varchar?).  Also, with this query I believe you are trying to get all rows that are less than 30 days old or the status != 'OUT', because your criteria for the background being red is `dt_in > 30 days and status == 'OUT'` and the logical negation of this (De Morgan's law) is `dt_in <= 30 days or status != 'OUT'`.

That being said if the $result77 query returned what it was supposed to the reasoning in your php code to make the background red if it is older than 30 days will never work if there is at least 1 row that is less than or equal to 30 days old or with a status not equal to OUT.  What you should do is either do two queries, 1 querying data that is `less than or equal to 30 days old or status not equal to OUT` and 1 querying the data that is `older than 30 days and has status equal to out`.  Or you can get rid of the `$result77 =..` query and replace the `if(!$result77)` with

```
if(time() - strtotime($row['dt_in']) <= 2592000 || $row['status'] != 'OUT') //2592000 sec == 30 days
```

Comment: this works excellent  for the date thing, i chnaged the < to > and now it changes all rows that are older than 30 days with status out to red, but i need it to turn red for everything not OUT

Comment: I think i finally got to a solution, using mostly all of your suggested answers. Did the css thing, modified the if(time() - strtotime($row thing ... and ended up with this... while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
if(time() - strtotime($row['dt_in']) > 2592000 && $row['status'] != 'OUT') //2592000 sec == 30 days
{
echo "<tr class='MyOut'>";
} else {
echo "<tr>";
}
  echo "<td>" . $row['who'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ref'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['asset'] . "</td>";

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading it right

```
$result77 = mysql_query($con,$sql77);
```

$result77 will always result in either TRUE (query worked) or FALSE (query failed). It doesn't change per row during your while loop. Checking the values in your $row array should fix the problem.

As suggested in the comments, you probably should use CSS (however for testing purposes, replacing " class='MyOut'" with " bgcolor='red'" should work).

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr";

  if ($row['status'] == 'OUT')
  {
    echo " class='MyOut'";
  }

  echo ">";

  ...remainder of output...

}
```

or

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr" . ($row['status'] == 'OUT' ? " class='MyOut'" : "") . ">";

  ...remainder of output...

}
```

Outside of the while loop, run this line (this makes the assumption that dt_in is a YYYY-MM-DD field. If it is something else, you need to amend the "Y-m-d" in the call below):

```
$cDate = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n"), date("j") - 30, date("Y")));
```

If both conditions are met:

```
if (($row['status'] == 'OUT') && ($row['dt_in'] <= $cDate))
```

If either conditions are met

```
if (($row['status'] == 'OUT') || ($row['dt_in'] <= $cDate))
```

Comment: Here is a very simple JSFiddle to give you an idea of what the output would look like. http://jsfiddle.net/ksvJ9/

Comment: excellent, I think I am making progress... got one line with a red background, could you possibly also who me how i would add the same for where the dt_in column has a date older than 30days? I am currently using this code in another location SELECT * FROM data WHERE dt_in < date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS selector `:nth-of-type( )`:

```
table tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #ccc; } <br />
```

There is a script way of doing so,  with PHP or Javascript,  but CSS is better due to the fact that the primary function of CSS is to style,  while PHP generates extra load to the server without need of doing so,  and javascript is good too but can be user disabled.

To signal a flagged row,  like more than 30 days,  just use the table flags you have,  **dt_out** and use a PHP condition to backgroun.color the row or the cell.  Better call a class from the PHP conditioned statement.